# If I want to sample rate constants of chemical reactions, what the distribution will be appropriate?

Tags: kinetics, computational-chemistry

For example, I have a (chemical) reaction systems, I want to sample the parameter space. What will be the best and validated distribution for sampling? And why?

Comment: (Can't comment, not enough rep. ...) Do you mean calculating the rate from a statistical mechanical ensemble (e.g. Molecular Dynamics)?

Comment: @InonS Yes, I think this might be one of the possible approaches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have accepted my proposal of using a free-energy calculation, you can use that in a combination with classical [Transition State Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_state_theory) (think of it as an extension to the [Arrhenius equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrhenius_equation)).

More practically, you can read-up, for example on

1. [GROAMCS](http://www.gromacs.org/Documentation/How-tos/Free_Energy_Calculations)
2. [NAMD](http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Training/Tutorials/freenergy-index.html)

For more options, see [this overview presentation](http://www.indiana.edu/~cheminfo/C372/Lectures/C372_L10.ppt).